# Maven dependency on web application

Tags: maven, web-applications, maven-3, war

My Eclipse project is structured as such:

- my.core.webapp (libs, java classes, web.xml, etc)
- my.extended.webapp (libs, java classes **AND** a dependency to
  *my.core.webapp*)

my.core.webapp pom:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.core.webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    .
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my.extended.webapp pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.core.webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

when I compile with maven I get various *package xyz does not exist* exceptions.

Is there a way (without having a 3rd project or using modules) to achieve that?

Comment: if you build `my.core.webapp` before `my.extended.webapp` you should not have problems. But it looks likeyou should use a multi module build

Comment: the problem with the multi module build is that I have to reference both the  extendend app in the core and the core in the extended app. Since the idea of the core app is to be used by many other "extended" app, I would like to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem based on @ritz-xavi answer.

my.core.webapp pom:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <webXml>${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

my.extended.webapp pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.core.webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.core.webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <type>war</type>
</dependency>
```

Including both the war and the jar classes did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do 2 things here.

The first thing will be to add `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` to your maven war plugin configuration in my.core.webapp pom.xml. So now it should look like

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The second thing to do will be to add `<classifier>classes</classifier>` while you are specifying my.core.webpp as a dependency in your my.extendend.webapp pom.xml. So it should now look like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>my.core.webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <type>war</type>
    <classifier>classes</classifier>
</dependency>
```

That should be all.

Comment: Hi @ritz-xavi , thanks for the reply; unfortunately I have now another error: " Failed to execute goal on project my.extended.webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.extended.webapp:war:1: Failure to find my.core.webapp:classes:1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

Comment: Did you build again your my.core.webapp before building my.extended.webapp ??